# Buying resources from your neighbor

Tags: 7-wonders

In 7 Wonders,when buying resources from your neighbor.  Do they have an unlimited supply of resources for you to buy, or just what is showing?  For example can I buy 3 stone from them when they only have 1 stone showing in their resource pile, or am I only allowed to buy up to the number they are showing?

Comment: I see this as a pertinent question. I don't find that the rules actually quantify the amount/number of resources that a player can buy form the neighbouring city.

Answer (score 13):

You can only buy the amount that they have.  Here are the relevant rules:

> The resources of a city are produced by its Wonder board, its brown cards, its gray cards, and some yellow cards.  To build a structure, a player’s city must produce the resources indicated on its card.  Example: Giza produces 2 Stones, 1 Clay, 1 Ore, 1 Papyrus and 1 Textile.
>
> Often,  a  player  will  want  to  build  a  structure  requiring  resources  he  or  she does not produce.If these resources are produced by a neighboring city – players sitting directly to the left or right of that player – the player will be able to purchase the missing resource(s) through commerce.

You are buying resources that they produce and the rules for production indicate that each symbol only produces one resource.

Note that you buying these resources does not prevent the owner or the person to the other side of the owner from using it.  The rule is a little weird, but each player can use each produced resource once:

> Selling a resource to a neighboring city DOES NOT prevent a player from using it, during the same turn, for his own construction purposes.

Comment: What if two neighbors want to buy the same 1 stone?  They both get to buy one?  Only one - buy how do you chose if that's the card they chose based on buying that one resource from you.  What do they do know with the useless card?

Comment: @user27983, Don't consider other players. The player and both of their neighbours each have access to the resources the player produces. So if a player produces 2 Stones and 1 Clay, they player may use 2 Stones and 1 Clay, their clockwise neighbour can buy 2 Stones and 1 Clay, and their counter-clockwise neighbour can buy 2 Stones and 1 Clay.

Comment: @user27983 Multiple players can use the same produced resource in a turn.  I added the relevant rule to my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can only able to buy the amount they are showing.  They don't have an unlimited supply of them.